# $\frac{X_T-X_C}{X_T}$ vs $\frac{X_T}{X_C}$ as a metric of treatment effect?

Tags: anova

I am attempting to understand the use (and misuse) of these two response metrics.

When comparing the effect of a treatment to the control:

- one approach is to calculate the relative effect of the treatment:

$$E_1 = \frac{X_T - X_C}{X_C}$$

- another approach is to calculate the ratio of the treatment response to the control response:

$$E_2 = \frac{X_T}{X_C} = E_1 + 1.$$

Do these indices have names? How do their meanings differ? Are there certain situations in which one is preferred to another?

---

*Note: this question has been modified from the original, hopefully providing clarity by removing specific study details.*

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your two factor RCBD using 2-way anova? Do you mean there were two factors and were randomized on multiple blocks? Also, depending on what X_i mean, D and T_i may be ok for interpretation. However, it is unclear what are X_i from the limited details you provide. Could you please be a bit more detailed?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the study?

Comment: @Nick and suncoolsu I think that the question would be clearer if it had less detail rather than more, my focus is really on the use and abuse of these metrics rather than the experimental design itself. Please advise and feel free to edit.

Comment: $X_T/X_C$ is just the ratio of means and it is also sometimes called the "response ratio". You can find it being used, for example, in meta-analyses in the field of ecology. See, for example: Hedges, L. V., Gurevitch, J., & Curtis, P. S. (1999). The meta-analysis of response ratios in experimental ecology. Ecology, 80(4), 1150-1156.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $E_2 = E_1 + 1$, the two measures are really saying the same thing.  I'd call them both "relative effect", and the choice between them is mostly a matter of taste: should you say 1.5-fold increase or 50% increase?  In practice, I'd lean towards $E_1$ if it is < 1 and $E_2$ if $E_1 > 1$.  I'm often annoyed by newspaper articles that say things like "a 453% increase".

The bigger distinction is between $E_2$ and $E_3 = X_T - X_C$.

Comment: thanks. I was thinking that these would behave differently with values of $X_c$ around 0, but now I see that they are equally sensitive.